# How to more efficiently write multiple EXISTS subquery in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm querying my database where a workflow has multiple of a specific property in a related table. I've managed to write a query that correctly gets the results but it is using multiple subqueries, and I'm sure there's a more efficient way to write it.

```
SELECT *
FROM   workflow w
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT ti.id
               FROM   task_instance ti
                      left join workflow_task_instance wti
                             ON ti.id = wti.task_instance_id
               WHERE  ti.task_type = 'TASK_ONE'
                      AND wti.workflow_id = w.id)
       AND EXISTS (SELECT ti.id
                   FROM   task_instance ti
                          left join workflow_task_instance wti
                                 ON ti.id = wti.task_instance_id
                   WHERE  ti.task_type = 'TASK_TWO'
                          AND wti.workflow_id = w.id);
```

How can I rewrite this to use just one subquery, or joins instead of subqueries?

Comment: One EXISTS, with a GROUP BY!

Comment: `where (select count(distinct ti.task_type) from task_instance ti inner join workflow_task_instance wti on wti.task_instance_id = ti.id where ti.task_type in ('TASK_ONE', 'TASK_TWO')) = 2`

Comment: You could also do `where exists (... having count(distinct ti.task_type) = 2)`

Comment: Or `having max(ti.task_type) <> min(ti.task_type)`.

Comment: @shawnt00 Got it to work! Thanks! Had to add back in the `wti.workflow_id = w.id` in the where clause but after fixing that this query is better according to explain analyze.

Comment: BTW, do `inner join` instead, since your wti.workflow_id condition turns the LEFT JOIN return INNER JOIN result.

Comment: Yes, I did accidently leave out that filter. And I had also used an inner join for the reason mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate which workflow_ids have both task_types using a  single subquery that uses a `GROUP BY` clause and a subsequent `HAVING` clause. Whist you could continue to use EXISTS with this single subquery approach; an `INNER JOIN` seems the more direct route.

```
SELECT w.*
FROM workflow w
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT wti.workflow_id
    FROM task_instance ti
    INNER JOIN workflow_task_instance wti ON ti.id = wti.task_instance_id
    WHERE ti.task_type IN ('TASK_ONE', 'TASK_TWO')
    GROUP BY wti.workflow_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ti.task_type) = 2
    ) subquery ON w.id = subquery.workflow_id
```

**nb**

- there is no point using a left join inside the subquery because unmatched rows (producing NULL in the workflow_id column) will be ignored anyway.
- because the subquery groups by workflow_id there will only be one row per workflow_id in the result, hence joining the subquery to the workflow table will not multiply the resultant rows (therefore removing a key advantage of using EXISTS).